# Caliburn.Micro modify logging level

Tags: logging, caliburn.micro, nlog

I am using Caliburn.Micro and NLOG.
I have build my logging according to this sample:
http://buksbaum.us/2010/08/08/how-to-do-logging-with-caliburn-micro/

This works well and as expected. But Caliburn  sets the level of all its messages to info. I would prefer them to be Debug Statements. Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the `NLogLogger` implementation of the `Info` method from:

```
public void Info(string format, params object[] args)
{
    _innerLogger.Info(format, args);
}
```

to

```
public void Info(string format, params object[] args)
{
    _innerLogger.Debug(format, args);
}
```

Comment: Ok, that was tooo obvious ;)
Is it best practice to use NLog directly for my own log-messages or should I use the Caliburn infrastructure?

Comment: It depends what you're happy to take a dependency on. I wouldn't recommend using Caliburn.Micro's as it wouldn't make sense outside of your presentation layer, and I'm not sure what the current state of NLog is, as the main developer has handed over the project. So if you're worried about NLog being too volatile a dependency, then you could either write your own logger abstraction, or use something like Common.Logging.

Comment: Another argument is that logging logic shouldn't be interspersed with business logic and that you should use AOP for a cross-cutting concern such as logging (something like PostSharp for example).

Comment: I fear that is too far ahead of my capabilities - I would like to dig into all these issues, but I am not a student anymore and mastered in the wrong field of study. So I have to learn all these things on the job - which is harder.
But I get your argument about dividd logic - so I will probably use NLOG and just use different targets for Caliburn and my other logging concerns. I am quite familiar to Nlog, so I will give it a shot - if it goes down, the harm would be surivable.